# keyframe animation image layering

Tags: z-index, css-animations, opacity, keyframe

I am trying to have one image come into view behind another one. Is it possible to use z-index/opacity to accomplish this? Below is the code I'm referring to. I'm using the background-position property to move things in-out of view.

```
@-webkit-keyframes bannerAnimation {
 0% {
background-position-x:
  -240px, 
  -160px,
  -240px,
  0;
 }
50% {
background-position-x:
  -240px, 
  -45px,
  -140px, 
  0;
} 
100% {
background-position-x: 
  117px,
  -65px,
  117px, 
  0;
}
0%, 48% {
background-position-y:
 -4000px,
  0px,
  480px,
  0px; 
} 
50%, 100% {
background-position-y:
  14px,
  0px,
  43px,
  0px; 
}
  0% {
opacity:
  0, 
  1,
  0,
  1;
}
50% {
opacity:
  0, 
  1,
  0, 
  1;
} 
100% {
opacity: 
  1,
  1,
  1, 
  1;
 }
}



#banner a#main .content {
background-image:
  url('../images/95x27_headline_2x.png'),
  url('../images/155x50_stephen_2x.png'),
  url('../images/41x4_copy_2x.png'),
  url('../images/320x50_bg_2x.png');
background-size:
  95px 27px, 
  155px 50px,
  41px 4px,
  320px 50px;
background-position-y:
  50px,
  0px,
  50px,
  0px;

-webkit-animation: bannerAnimation 6s ease forwards;
```

Answer (score 1):

to achieve what you are trying to do I would suggest using seperate divs for seperate images.

Then instead of animating *background-position*, try animating the z-index itself.

```
@keyframes move {
  from { z-index: 0; transform: scale(1); }
  to { z-index: 4; transform: scale(2.5); }
}
```

Check out this example on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/gboJf) to get you started in the right direction :)

Comment: Use `transform: translateZ(n);` instead of `z-index` since it won't cause any repaints/reflows and uses the GPU to process the animation.